# derivative $\frac{\ln{x}}{e^x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im asked to solve find the derivative of: $$ \frac{\ln x}{e^x}$$
**my attempt**
$$D\frac{\ln x}{e^x} = \frac{\frac{1}{x}e^x + \ln (x) e^x}{e^x} = e^x \frac{\frac{1}{x}+\ln x}{e^{2x}} = \frac{\frac{1}{x}+\ln x}{e^x}$$

But this is apparently wrong and the correct answer is: 
$$\frac{\frac{1}{x} - \ln x}{e^x}$$

**Where do I go wrong?**

Comment: $e^x\cfrac{\frac{1}{x}+\ln{x}}{e^2x}$ should be $e^x\cfrac{\frac{1}{x}+\ln{x}}{e^{2x}} $. In LaTeX, it raises only the first symbol ahead of `^`, for example: `e^2x` $= e^2x$ and `e^{2x}` $ = e^{2x}$. If more than one symbol, you need to enclose it inside `{}`.

Answer (score 4):

Recall the formula:

$$\left(\dfrac{u}{v}\right)'=\dfrac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$

You forgot the minus sign!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of carrying around the quotient rule in your brain, I'd stick with just the product rule. In this case

$$\left(\ln(x)e^{-x}\right)'=\frac{1}{x} e^{-x}+\ln(x)(-e^{-x})=e^{-x}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\ln(x)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

you will need the quotient rule and we get $$\frac{\frac{1}{x}e^{x}-\ln(x)e^{x}}{(e^x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use correct Quotient rule, D(u/v) = (u' v -  u v') / v^2

```
                       D( lnx / e^x )  = ( 1/x * e^x - lnx * e^x )/ e^2x
                                       = ( 1/x - lnx)/e^x
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$ \frac{\ln x}{e^x}=e^{-x}\ln {x}$$
And
$$(uv)'=u'v+uv'$$
Thus
$$ (\frac{\ln x}{e^x})'=(e^{-x}\ln {x})'=(-e^{-x}\ln {x})+(\frac{e^{-x}}{x})=\frac{\frac{1}{x} - \ln x}{e^x}$$